# How to use grpc-web without envoy

Tags: grpc, grpc-web

I am playing with `grpc` & `grpc-web`. I was able to run a simple grpc server and grpc-web applications. However I feel like the setup requires too many dependencies `web-server`, `grpc-server` and `envoy proxy`.

Is anyone successfully using `grpc-web` for production? Do we need all the dependencies including envoy?

Comment: You need something that are able to understand and translate the grpc-web requests to your grpc server. The current default proxy which supports this out of the box is Envoy.

Answer (score 0):

We are using the grpc web proxy from improbable. So what you need is :

1. Generated js client  + grpc web runtime module
2. Grpc web proxy
3. Your implementation of grpc services
   Nothing special...

Comment: I already follow that. My question is - do we need envoy? Your application is in production? Can you share the link please? just curious.

Comment: You need some grpc web proxy. No way to call grpc server directly from the browser (meanwhile )

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we need some kind of proxy, but instead of [Envoy proxy](https://www.envoyproxy.io) you can use build in solutions like [grpcweb](https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/tree/master/go/grpcweb).